# Could there be any issues using "ns" as a subdomain?

Tags: domains, subdomain

I want to setup a subdomain "ns" on my domain, but before I do want to double check if there could be any potential issues using such a subdomain.

For example ns.mywebsite.com

To my knowledge, there shouldn't be, but I know a lot of nameservers are just named ns#.domain.com (e.g. ns1.domain.com ns2.domain.com) so I don't know if that could cause any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some subdomains are reserved for specific purposes in DNS, like `_domainkey` for email authentication.

That being said, I don't believe that `ns` is one of those reserved subdomains, so you should be able to use it for whatever you want.

Actually, after doing some more research it seems like [as long as you stay away from underscores, you should be fine](http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html). (Underscores for actual hostnames [seem to cause trouble anyways](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/underscore-in-subdomain-fails/31431/3).)

Comment: By the way, I was inspired by your question so I posed this more general one to Webmasters SE: [List of reserved third-level DNS zones?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120307/list-of-reserved-third-level-dns-zones)

Comment: Underscores *for actual hostnames* don't just cause trouble, they're not permitted by the RFC.

Comment: @AC Like some schmuck at the ietf is gonna tell me how I'm allowed use my domain name. Hold my beer http://_.maxl.us/

Comment: Okay so they won't give me an ssl cert for it and half the DNS resolvers won't resolve it. But my principle stands.

Comment: This comment chain is hilarious and should end up being posted somewhere.

Comment: Underscores are not allowed in hostnames. They exist only in domain names (this is a terminology from the original RFCs on DNS. Basically you have names in the DNS where **any** character is allowed, and then you have hostnames as a subset of them where only digits letters and hyphens are allowed).

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic in the prefix names of a DNS entry.  You can name them whatever you want.  Obviously, some people will think name server as you've already pointed out but the DNS servers won't be confused.

Comment: "There's no magic in the prefix names of a DNS entry." This is mostly right and will correspond to end-users experiment. However for troubleshooting there are now prefixes with specific semantics, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8509.txt. In short a name such as `root-key-sentinel-not-ta-<key-tag>` under specific circumstances will trigger specific behaviour.