# List of reserved third-level DNS zones?

Tags: dns, subdomain

The DNS zone name `_domainkeys` is used for email authentication through TXT records. The zone names `_tcp` and `_udp` are used to advertise application availability through SRV records.

Naturally, a webmaster would want to be sure not to use these zone names for anything else - only in accordance with the specs.

Are there any other such zone names with strict specs that a webmaster should take care not to use by accident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscores are not allowed in **host names** so I doubt they can "accidentally" be chosen to name a website.

Using underscores as a selector is a debate in itself among relevant circles, because basically they can be seen as a cheap way to do something without having to create a new DNS resource record type.

Anyway, the following two documents currently being discussed may give more context and data:

- https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-dnsop-attrleaf-16.txt
- https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-dnsop-attrleaf-fix-07.txt

Section 4.3 of the first one gives the following list of underscore cases:

```
        +------------+---------------------+-------------+
        | RR Type    | _NODE NAME          | REFERENCE   |
        +------------+---------------------+-------------+
        | *          | _example            | Section 4.5 |
        | NULL       | _ta-* {Section 4.4} | [RFC8145]   |
        | OPENPGPKEY | _openpgpkey         | [RFC7929]   |
        | SMIMEA     | _smimecert          | [RFC8162]   |
        | SRV        | _dccp               | [RFC2782]   |
        | SRV        | _http               | [RFC4386]   |
        | SRV        | _ipv6               | [RFC5026]   |
        | SRV        | _ldap               | [RFC4386]   |
        | SRV        | _ocsp               | [RFC4386]   |
        | SRV        | _sctp               | [RFC2782]   |
        | SRV        | _sip                | [RFC5509]   |
        | SRV        | _tcp                | [RFC2782]   |
        | SRV        | _udp                | [RFC2782]   |
        | SRV        | _xmpp               | [RFC3921]   |
        | TLSA       | _dane               | [RFC7671]   |
        | TLSA       | _sctp               | [RFC6698]   |
        | TLSA       | _tcp                | [RFC6698]   |
        | TLSA       | _udp                | [RFC6698]   |
        | TXT        | _acme-challenge     | [ACME]      |
        | TXT        | _dmarc              | [RFC7489]   |
        | TXT        | _domainkey          | [RFC6376]   |
        | TXT        | _mta-sts            | [MTA-STS]   |
        | TXT        | _spf                | [RFC7208]   |
        | TXT        | _tcp                | [RFC6763]   |
        | TXT        | _udp                | [RFC6763]   |
        | TXT        | _vouch              | [RFC5518]   |
        | URI        | _acct               | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _dccp               | [RFC7566]   |
        | URI        | _email              | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _ems                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _fax                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _ft                 | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _h323               | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _iax                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _ical-access        | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _ical-sched         | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _ifax               | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _im                 | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _mms                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _pres               | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _pstn               | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _sctp               | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _sip                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _sms                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _tcp                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _udp                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _unifmsg            | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _vcard              | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _videomsg           | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _voice              | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _voicemsg           | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _vpim               | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _web                | [RFC6118]   |
        | URI        | _xmpp               | [RFC6118]   |
        +------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

The whole purposes of these new specifications is to create a "IANA registry" of all underscore cases like that. If they get approved (they should be but noone knows when), then at some point you will get a new entry below https://www.iana.org/protocols that lists all specified cases of DNS names using an underscore.

Also, separately, while not a zone and no underscores, there are now specific DNS names that may trigger specific behavior so one should refrain from using them. But they are constructed in such a way that it is "impossible" to reuse these names just by chance.

Look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8509.txt : names like `root-key-sentinel-is-ta-<key-tag>` or `root-key-sentinel-not-ta-<key-tag>` under specific circumstances will trigger specific behavior from a compliant resolver. This is used to help troubleshooting DNSSEC cases.

Comment: Do you know if there are any non-underscore zone names besides `www` and maybe `m` that have very strong semantics around their use?

Comment: Not sure to follow you but "in the past" thing like `ftp.example.com` was supposed to be an FTP server, `mail.example.com` an email receiver, etc. but those are all human conventions, you can call your website by `https://mail.example.com/` and it will technically work the same way than `https://www.example.com/` except that it may confuse visitors indeed.

Comment: I found a relevant RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8552.html (from march 2019) `Scoped Interpretation of DNS Resource Records through "Underscored" Naming of Attribute Leaves`. And here is the IANA list: https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#underscored-globally-scoped-dns-node-names

Comment: Somehow the ietf.org links are now 404s...

Comment: @oliverpool RFC8552 **IS** the result of  `draft-ietf-dnsop-attrleaf`, amd RFC8553 is `draft-ietf-dnsop-attrleaf-fix`. This is the normal process of the IETF. The drafts mature, if enough interest and work, and then become an RFC.